# Swift 3 - iOS 10 - UITextField - how to auto hide keyboard and auto move the text field up

Tags: uitextfield, swift3, ios10

My question is very specifically for iOS 10 and swift 3 as ive tried multiple solutions for this problem but they don't work due to swift 3. I have also tried converting the code and enabling legacy code. All of those doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if you can post the code and simple steps to automatically move the text field up then inputing the text and upon tapping the return key the text field should go back to its original place and keyboard disappear.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This example works on Swift 3:

extend `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.nicknameLabel.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nicknameLabel.delegate = self
    }
```

Here are some tips that works for Swift 3:
https://medium.com/@KaushElsewhere/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-a-view-controller-of-ios-3b1bfe973ad1#.2fw5cflmp

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It works perfectly for dismissing the keyboard with your solution, what about if the text field is at the bottom of the page. How do you move the text field up so the keyboard doesn't hide it.

Answer (score 2):

First put UITextField in a scroll view.

Then have this little extension:

```
extension UIScrollView {

 /// listen to keyboard event
 func makeAwareOfKeyboard() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardDidHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
 }

 /// move scroll view up
 func keyBoardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo as NSDictionary?
    let rectValue = info![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let kbSize = rectValue.cgRectValue.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height, 0)
    self.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

 }

 /// move scrollview back down
 func keyBoardDidHide(notification: Notification) {
    // restore content inset to 0
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollIndicatiorInsets = contentInsets
 }
}
```

Then make that scroll view aware of keyboard

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    scrollView.makeAwareOfKeyboard()
    ...
}
```